# Не работает stick-master слайдер

Tags: javascript, html

Недавно скачал `slider-master`. При переносе кода `slider` не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $(".regular").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-slide {
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  opacity: .2;
}

.slick-active {
  opacity: .5;
}

.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<section class="regular slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: А как он хоть себя ведет после подключения? Мы догадываться должны?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто пути указывают не туда. Подставил в ваш код ссылки из CDN, всё работает. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/slick-carousel

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css">
      <style>
        html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

        * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
        }

        .slick-slide {
        margin: 0px 20px;
        }

        .slick-slide img {
        width: 100%;
        }

        .slick-prev:before,
        .slick-next:before {
        color: black;
        }


        .slick-slide {
        transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
        opacity: .2;
        }

        .slick-active {
        opacity: .5;
        }

        .slick-current {
        opacity: 1;
        }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <section class="regular slider">
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
        </div>
      </section>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).on('ready', function() {
          $(".regular").slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3
          });
        });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Кстати `type="text/css"` и `type="text/javascript"` в html5 указывать не нужно.